# How to add an element to its rightful place in a sorted array in java

Tags: java

So I created this amazon catalog program for class using an arraylist and part 2 of this project was to actually change the project to use an array instead of an arraylist and I did that fine, now part 3 of this project is to modify the add method so that instead of just adding the item to the end of the array it adds the item to its rightful spot in an already sorted array using insertion sort.  My problem is this, I was getting errors for my add method because of the way I initialize my catalog,  I actually use my add method to initialize it so when I had my compareTo method being used in my add method i would get an error on the first call because the first item had nothing to compare to.  I then added an if else case where i wanted it to only do a comparison if it wasnt the first item being added but this didnt work either.

Here is my add method in my catalog class

```
/*this class creates an object of type catalog used to put items into and defines
methods used to manipulate this catalog object*/
public class Catalog
{

    private Item[] items;
    private final int MAXSIZE = 20;
    private int size;//how many items are in the array


    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Catalog
     */
    public Catalog()
    {
        //makes empty arraylist
        // initialise instance variables
        items = new Item[MAXSIZE];
        size = 0;

    }

    /**
     * An example of a method - replace this comment with your own
     *
     * @param  y  a sample parameter for a method
     * @return    the sum of x and y
     */
    public void addItem(Item theItem)
    {
        // put your code here
        /*items[size] = theItem;
        size++;*/
        int position = MAXSIZE;

        if(size != 0){ //only compare items when its not the first item being added
            while (position > 0 && theItem.compareTo(items[position - 1])<0){
                items[position] = items[position - 1];
                position --;
            }
            items[position] = theItem;
        }
        else {//if its the first item being added
        items[size] = theItem;
        size++;
    }

    }
```

here is my catalog initialization in my CatalogInterface class

```
//this class creates an initial catalog and collects input from the user
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class CatalogInterface
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own


    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class CatalogInterface
     */
    private String name;
    private Catalog cat;
    private String userChoice;
    private String type;
    private int itemNum;
    private String title;
    private double price;
    private String author;
    private String star;
    private String artist;
    public CatalogInterface(String name)
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        this.name = name;
        this.cat = new Catalog();
        //CREATE ARRAYLIST HERE
        cat.addItem(new Music(1111,"White and Nerdy",2.50,"\"Weird Al\" Yankovic"));
        cat.addItem(new Music(2222,"Amish Paradise",2.22,"\"Weird Al\" Yankovic"));
        cat.addItem(new Music(3333,"The Saga Begins",2.00,"\"Weird Al\" Yankovic"));
        cat.addItem(new Movie(4444,"UHF",9.99,"\"Weird Al\" Yankovic"));
        cat.addItem(new Movie(5555,"The Dark Crystal",8.99,"\"Jim Henson"));
        cat.addItem(new Movie(6666,"Die Hard",13.99,"Bruce Willis"));
        cat.addItem(new Book(7777,"When I Grow Up",7.98,"\"Weird Al\" Yankovic"));
        cat.addItem(new Book(8888,"The Chronicles of Pern: First Fall",5.99,"\"Anne McCaffrey"));
        cat.addItem(new Book(9999,"Get gud you scrub",2.50,"Steve \"Troll\" Rathier"));
        cat.addItem(new Movie(6969,"The Adventures of Mr. Winky", 9.99, "Richard Dickinson"));

    }
```

Comment: why not using a sorted List?

Comment: because my project states that I must use an array.  the point of this project is to show how you can make changes to a program without making changes to my main method at all so I need to use the same method signatures and it must be with an array

Comment: do a binary search on the array as is, enter the element where it needs to be entered, after shifting all the elements following it

Comment: Hi, Please try to add a minimal example, when you're asking a question. [Here's a link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @ThisaruG he did.