# Adding an object to a sorted array into the correct spot

Tags: java

So I have this project and im writing the add method for my catalog class and this add method needs to add an item to a sorted array into the right place using insertion sort, unless the array has nothing in it in that case i just want to add it in normally.  this whole project must use an array I cannot use an arraylist or anything else.

The problem I am having here is that the way my program currently is, its only adding one object to my array and each time i try to add a new one during run tine it jst replaces the item already in there.  I know that my problem is something in the body of my while loop and the way i initialize my position variable.

here is the method im having trouble with.

```
public void addItem(Item theItem)
    {
        int position = size;

        if(size != 0){
            while (position > 0 && theItem.compareTo(items[position - 1]) < 0){
                items[position] = items[position - 1];
                position--;
            }
            items[position] = theItem;
        }
        else{
        items[size] = theItem;
        size++;
    }
```

here is my compareTo method

```
public int compareTo(Item other){
        if(this.getItemType().equals(other.getItemType())){
           return this.itemnum - other.itemnum;
        }
        //item types are not equal
        else
        return this.getItemType().compareTo(other.getItemType());
        //try writing code to compare by price as well
    }
```

Comment: How is this question different from your previous question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58607308/how-to-add-an-element-to-its-rightful-place-in-a-sorted-array-in-java?noredirect=1#comment103525391_58607308

Comment: If the array is sorted, you can use binary search.

Comment: @Glains he was already recommended to do that yesterday.

Comment: I cant use a binary search I have to do it in a way similar to this,  I was told that my problem is in the body of my  loop

Comment: Arrays are fixed size. You can't add or remove items to/from them, only replace existing items. To extend or reduce an array you need to create a new array and copy values to it. Lists can be extended or reduced.

Comment: yes what im trying to do is.  compare an item to the item at the end of the array, if that item is less than that current item, copy that current item to the spot to the right of it.  then compare the same item to the next array item and if the item is more than that item it will be placed just after that item where the last item was previously.

Comment: You mean if you have `[1,2,3,5]` and adds `4` the end result would be `[1,2,3,4,5]`? If so, that array has grown. Arrays in Java can't grow. You would need to allocate a new array 1 item larger than the old array and copy the old array to the new array.

Comment: ohh I see what youre saying so Ive already initialized this array to size 20 and there are only 10 items being added to the array so i have room to shift items.

Comment: And that's why you should create a [complete, minimal, reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we have that kind of information.

Comment: I apologize, I forgot about that line

Comment: i'm wonder , depending on which fields in your item you are comparing?

Comment: first comparing by item type then by item number

Comment: items[position-1] = items[position] make you loose the value of items[position-1] ! it surely a wrong algorithmes

Answer (score 2):

The most likely problem in your code is this line:

```
items[position-1] = items[position];
```

This will copy an item in you array from the current position to the position to the left of it.

When you insert a new item you want to copy items from the left to the current position to make room for the new item to the left.

Change it to

```
items[position] = items[position-1];
```

A `size++` is also missing after the `while` block, inside the first `if` block.

I realized this when adding a second call to `addItem` in my test code below.

You could also put a single `size++` statement outside of the `if` statement.

---

A Complete, Minimal, Reproducible Example that I used trying to fix it. I have used `Integer` instead of `Item` to avoid having to add more classes.

```
public class Main {
  private int size = 0;
  private Integer[] items = new Integer[20];

  public static void main(String... args) {
    new Main().execute();  // Moving us into a non-static context
  }

  public void execute() {
    System.arraycopy(new Integer[] {1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9}, 0, items, 0, 8);
    size = 8;
    // items = [1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,null,null,...]

    addItem(5);
    addItem(5); // test adding a second item

    // items = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,null,null,...]
    for (Integer i : items) {
      System.out.println(i);
    }
  }

  public void addItem(Integer item) {
    int position = size;
    if (size != 0) {
      while (position > 0 && item.compareTo(items[position - 1]) < 0) {
        // items[position-1] = items[position]; // Result [1,2,3,4,5,null,null,...]
        items[position] = items[position-1]; // Result [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,null,null,...]
        position--;
      }
      items[position] = item;
      size++; // this line was missing as well
    } else {
      items[size] = item;
      size++;
    }
    // or a single size++; here, removing the other two
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this did not change anything.  I tried the debugger and it seems that the items[position] = items[position = 1];  position--;  code isnt running, its going straight to items[position] = theItem and thats why im only getting one item in there.

Comment: I've added the code I used to recreate the problem. Compare it with your own code and see if you spot any differences.

Comment: If, as you say, your code never reaches the `while` body, you also have an error in your `compareTo` implementation.

Comment: @SteveRats I updated my answer. There was a second error in the code that didn't show up if only adding 1 item.

Answer (score 0):

The ugly solution by making new array

```
public int[] addItem(int item, int[] items){
                int[] tempArr = new int[items.length + 1];
                boolean hasAlready = false;
                for(int i = 0 ; i < items.length; i++){
                        if(hasAlready)tempArr[i + 1] = items[i];
                        else if(item < items[i]){
                                tempArr[i] = item;
                                tempArr[i + 1] = items[i];
                                hasAlready = true;
                        }else {
                                tempArr[i] = items[i];
                        }
                }
                //items = tempArr; if items is global variable
                return tempArr;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

One can use existing utility functions, [`Arrays.binarySearch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(T%5B%5D,int,int,T,java.util.Comparator)), and `System.arraycopy`. Your loop was 1 off.

```
public void addItem(Item theItem) {
    Comparator<Item> comparator = Comparator.comparing(Item::getItemType)
                                            .thenComparingInt(it -> it.itemnum);
    int position = Arrays.binarySearch(items, 0, size, theItem, comparator);
    // If position >= 0 the item was found (maybe no need to insert?)
    if (position < 0) {
        position = ~position; // Insert position of not found item
    }
    System.arraycopy(items, position, items, position + 1, size - position);
    items[position] = theItem;
    size++;
}
```

Binary search results in the non-negative index when found, or the negative ~index when not found. Here binary search is done on a subarray from 0 upto size (excluded).

Answer (score 0):

Same as Roger Gustavsson

```
public class Main {
    private int size = 0;
    private Integer[] items = new Integer[20];

    public static void main(String... args) {
        new Main().execute();  // Moving us into a non-static context
    }

    public void execute() {
        System.arraycopy(new Integer[] {1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9}, 0, items, 0, 8);
        size = 8;
        // items = [1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,null,null,...]
        addItem(5);
        // items = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,null,null,...]
        for (Integer i : items) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

    public void addItem(Integer item) {
        if (size == 0) {
            items[size] = item;
            size++;
            return;
        }
        int position = size;
        while (position > 0 && item.compareTo(items[position - 1]) < 0) {
            items[position] = items[position - 1];
            position--;
        }
        items[position] = item;
        size++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

on what you are trying to achieve, i think next solution will be starting point from where you can build your own solution depending your specific needs. i have Changed your main method a little bit, and i do not know if your classes implements comparable /Comparator or not.

```
public void addItem(Item theItem) {
    int position = position(items, theItem); // position is a method that finds best position for inseriton
    if (items[position] == null){ // if items at best position is null then add new element there
        items[position] = theItem;
    } else{
        items[size] = theItem; // if not add element at last position
        swapUp(size); // and swap them up to perfect position.
    }

    size++;

}
```

method that find best position looks like this.

```
 private static int position(Item[] items, Item newItem) {
    if (isEmpty(items))
        return 0;

    int pos=0;
    int target=items.length-1;

    while(pos < target){
        int m = pos+(target-pos)/2;
        if (items[m] !=null){
            if(newItem.getNumber()>items[m].getNumber()){ // comparing depending on item number
                pos=m+1;
            }else{
                target=m;
            }
        }else{
            target = m;
        }

    }

    return pos;
}
```

as you can see method is looking for position depending on item number, you can change this with your type, or do both type and number comparison.  Swaping up is handled by thus 2 method.

```
private void swapUp(int lastPosition){
    if (lastPosition == -1){
        return;
    }
    Item lastItem = items[lastPosition];
    Item p = items[lastPosition-1];
    if (lastItem.getNumber() < p.getNumber())
        replace(lastPosition, lastPosition-1);
    else
        lastPosition = 0;
    swapUp(lastPosition-1);

}

private void replace(int from, int to){
    Item temporary = items[from];
    items[from] = items[to];
    items[to] = temporary;
}
```

and again i'm doing comparison of numbers you can implement any kind of comparison you want. i saw your previous question and modeled your classes

> 

```
Music{number=1111, name='White and Nerdy', price=2.5, pro='"Weird Al" Yankovic'}
Music{number=2222, name='Amish Paradise', price=2.22, pro='"Weird Al" Yankovic'}
Music{number=3333, name='The Saga Begins', price=2.0, pro='"Weird Al" Yankovic'}
Movie{number=4444, name='UHF', price=9.99, pro='"Weird Al" Yankovic'}
Movie{number=5555, name='The Dark Crystal', price=8.99, pro='"Jim Henson'}
Movie{number=6666, name='Die Hard', price=13.99, pro='Bruce Willis'}
Movie{number=6969, name='The Adventures of Mr. Winky', price=9.99, pro='Richard Dickinson'}
Book{number=7777, name='When I Grow Up', price=7.98, pro='"Weird Al" Yankovic'}
Book{number=8888, name='The Chronicles of Pern: First Fall', price=5.99, pro='"Anne McCaffrey'}
Book{number=9999, name='Get gud you scrub', price=2.5, pro='Steve "Troll" Rathier'}
```

as you can see they are in sorted order.